# Why are these not bases in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that bases vectors must span and be linearly independent.

The (i) is not bases because the last vector contains $\pi$.
The (iii) is not bases because they are not linearly independent.
The (iv) is not bases because there are only 3 vectors here and bases for $\mathbb{R}^4$ must contain at least 4 vectors.
The (v) is not bases because they do not span.
What about (ii), is it a basis?

[image]

Comment: Note that any set that contains the zero vector must be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(ii) contains only 3 linearly independent vectors, so cannot span a 4-dimensional space.

Also, your answer for (i) is wrong: the $\pi$ is irrelevant. Count the vectors again. Can they be linearly independent?

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(i) contains 5 vectors, so they can certainly not be linearly independent.  Similarly, (iv) only contains 3 vectors, so certainly cannot span a 4-d space.

(iii) notice that the fourth vector is a multiple of the second one